# Neo4j server plugin directory

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to install GDS on a neo4j server (`Linux`, `EC2`), community edition. But there is no `plugins` directory, I only have `bin` and `lib`.

Is it possible to create one next to `lib` and `bin`?

Also when I try to dump my graph I get permission error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should only ask 1 question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create the `plugins` directory unless you want it in a non-default location.

On EC2, the neo4j directories (like `plugins)` are *usually* under `/var/lib/neo4j`. And the configuration files are *usually* under `/etc/neo4j`.

And here is how to figure out the location for sure, assuming the neo4j server is already installed:

1. Execute `sudo systemctl status neo4j`.
2. Look at the "Loaded: ..." line in the result, and copy the `neo4j.service` path (e.g., "/usr/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service").
3. Execute `grep Environment <...neo4j.service path...>`. You'll get a result like:

   ```
   Environment="NEO4J_CONF=/etc/neo4j" "NEO4J_HOME=/var/lib/neo4j"
   ```
4. The config files are under the `NEO4J_CONF` directory, and the special neo4j directories are under the `NEO4J_HOME` directory.

Unfortunately, the above environment variables are not available from the command line.

As for your second question (which should have been posed in a new SO Question), all neo4j commands need to be executed as the `neo4j` user. To do that, you can use this command: `sudo -u neo4j <neo4j-command>`

Comment: Thanks, As you mentioned neo4j_home is under "NEO4J_HOME=/var/lib/neo4j", but still there is no default PLUGINS folder, can I make it manually and copy the jar file there?

Comment: Yes, but make sure the plugins directory location agrees with its [configuration setting](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_server.directories.plugins).